# How to add a new Transform after the R8Transform on the Android Gradle Plugin?

Tags: android, gradle, android-r8

I want insert some code into all methods after R8Transform. how can i make it?

When I use `registerTransform()` in my plugin, it always happen before R8Transform.

I think i can do this use reflect（hacker R8Transform），Is this the only way?